# Protocol Not Found Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, webview

I am having trouble with downloading the image from my url it is saying that the protocol is not found and as you can see in my screenshot [HttpURLConnection Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUTEq.png)
that the url have an "http://" attached to it. I have read and tried all other solutions in this site but to no avail.

This is my current source that I am working on.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DBHandler myDB;
    public String defaultURL = "http://ae1230ohx8.smartrelease.jp/eflends/"; // Default URL
    private WebView webView;
    private String selectedLinkTitle; //link that was passed from FavoriteList
    private String searchedURL; // search URL from MainMenu (Search field)
    Map<String,String> listFavoriteDataDB;//links and id from Favorites table DB

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebViewClient mWebViewClient = new WebViewClient();
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(mWebViewClient);


        myDB = new DBHandler(this);

        final ImageView favoriteBtn =  (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.favorite);
        final ImageView menuBtn =  (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.mainmenu);
        final ImageView backBtn = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.backMainView);

        getDBData(); //get the data

        //set the onclick listener for favorite btn
        favoriteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick( View v )
            {


                String webUrl = webView.getUrl();
                String webUrlTitle = webView.getTitle();
                Boolean isFavorite = isFave(webUrl);

                if(webUrl!="") {
                    if(isFavorite.equals(false)){
                        myDB.insertData(webUrl, webUrlTitle);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "お気に入りに追加されました。", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        favoriteBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.favorites_added);

                        webView.evaluateJavascript("document.head.querySelector(\"[property='og:image']\").content", new ValueCallback<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onReceiveValue(String s) {
                                getBitmapFromURL(s);
                            }
                        });

                    } else {
                        if(webUrl.contains("/lens/")) {
                            if (webUrl.contains("ef-l")) {
                                favoriteBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.favorites_notadded_white);
                            } else {
                                favoriteBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.favorites_notadded);
                            }
                        } else {

                            favoriteBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.favorites_notadded);

                        }
                        deleteFavorite(webUrlTitle);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        //set the onclick listener for menu btn
        menuBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick( View v )
            {
            String webUrl = webView.getUrl();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainMenu.class);
            intent.putExtra("currentURL",webUrl);
            startActivity(intent);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_from_right, R.anim.slide_to_left);
            }
        });

        //set the onclick listener for back button
        backBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick( View v )
            {
                if(webView.canGoBack())
                    webView.goBack();
            }
        });


        loadWeb();
    }


    public void loadWeb(){
        //        //dynamically sets the button if the url is found in the db
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

            final ImageView favoriteBtn =  (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.favorite);
            final ImageView menuBtn =  (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.mainmenu);
            final ImageView logo =  (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.logo);
            final Toolbar toolbar =  (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar3);
            final TextView border =  (TextView)findViewById(R.id.border);
            final ImageView backBtn = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.backMainView);

            @Override
            public void onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(WebView view, HttpAuthHandler handler, String host, String realm) {
                handler.proceed("eflends", "test");
            }

            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon){

                favoriteBtn.setEnabled(true);

                if(url.contains("/lens/")) {
                    if (url.contains("ef-l")) {
                        toolbar.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(Color.BLACK)); //make the bar black
                        menuBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.main_menu_white);
                        logo.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo_canon01);
                        border.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#444444"));
                        backBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_arrow_left_white);

                        favoriteBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.favorites_notadded_white);


                    } else {
                        toolbar.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE)); //make it white
                        menuBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.mainmenu);
                        logo.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo_canon02);
                        border.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f0f0f0"));
                        backBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_arrow_left);

                        favoriteBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.favorites_notadded);


                    }

                } else {

                    toolbar.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE)); //make it white for all
                    menuBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.mainmenu);
                    logo.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo_canon02);
                    border.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f0f0f0"));
                    backBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_arrow_left);

                    favoriteBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.favorites_notadded);


                }

                if(webView.canGoBack()){
                    backBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    backBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }

                //check if url already exist.
                if(listFavoriteDataDB != null && listFavoriteDataDB.containsValue(url)){
                    favoriteBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.favorites_added);
                }

            }

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){


                if(webView.canGoBack()){
                    backBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    backBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }

            }

        });

        loadURL();
    }

    public boolean isFave(String webUrl){
        listFavoriteDataDB = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Cursor data = myDB.isFavorite(webUrl);
        int rowCount = data.getCount();
        if(rowCount != 0){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void getDBData(){

        //get the urls from the db
        listFavoriteDataDB = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Cursor data = myDB.getAllData();

        while(data.moveToNext()) {
            listFavoriteDataDB.put(data.getString(1), data.getString(2)); //put title(key) and url(value)
        }

    }

    public void loadURL() {
        webView.loadUrl(defaultURL);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        Window decorView = getWindow();
        // Hide the status bar.
        decorView.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        // Calls the menu again.
//        invalidateOptionsMenu();
        Log.e("APP :", "onResume");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);

        String link = "";

        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        //get the name that was passed
        selectedLinkTitle = extras.getString("title");
        searchedURL       = extras.getString("url");
        String menuLink = extras.getString("linkFromMenu");

        //check if there is a passed value from favorite activity
        if (selectedLinkTitle!=null || searchedURL!=null || menuLink!= null) {

            if(selectedLinkTitle != null) {
                link = listFavoriteDataDB.get(selectedLinkTitle);
                Log.e("APP :", "loadURL - favorites");
            } else if (searchedURL != null){
                link = searchedURL.toString();
                Log.e("APP :", "loadURL - search");
            } else if (menuLink != null){
                link = menuLink.toString();
                Log.e("APP :", "load -" + menuLink);
            }

        }

        webView.loadUrl(link);
        Log.e("APP :", "onNewIntent");
    }

    public void deleteFavorite(String title) {
        int itemID = getItemID(title);
        myDB.deleteFavoriteURL(itemID,title);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "削除されました。", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    public int getItemID(String title){
        Cursor data = myDB.getItemID(title); //get the itemID from Title

        int itemID = -1;

        while(data.moveToNext()){
            itemID = data.getInt(0); //get the ID
        }
        if(itemID > -1) {
            return itemID;
        }else{
            return itemID;
        }
    }


    public void getBitmapFromURL(String imageUrl) {

        try {
            URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), imageUrl, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you paste your source code, would be easier to help you.

But I'm, already had to download images without using picasso, here goes the AsyncTask I've used:

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;

import br.com.soutsapp.Souts_v3.R;

public class ImageDonwloaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;

public ImageDonwloaderTask(ImageView imageView){
    imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
}

@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
    return getBitmapFromURL(params[0]);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
    if (isCancelled()) {
        bitmap = null;
    }

    ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
    if (imageView != null ) {
        if(bitmap != null) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
        else {
            imageView.setImageDrawable(imageView.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        }
    }
}

public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
    Bitmap myBitmap = null;

    try {
        if(src != null){
            String newUrl = src.replace(" ", "%20");
            java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL(newUrl);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("SOUTS", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

    return myBitmap;
}
}
```

Comment: I found out that I have not added my download image code in a Async task function.